# MYSQL Query Formatting

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have written a mysql query to retrieve data using nodejs api. All works fine but I want to change the data format. My data format is:

```
"data": [
    {
        "Name": "faseeh tauheed,Muhammad  Saeed,Farhan Khan",
        "Email": "faseeh@gmail.com,saeed@gmail.com,farhan@gmail.com",
        "Contact": "923158414969,923132347067,923471220797",
        "Skill": "HTML",
        "Experience": "36,72,48"
    }
]
```

but I want the record of each individual in a single line like this:

```
"faseeh tauheed", "faseeh@gmail.com", "923158414969", "HTML", "36"
```

I'm facing ambiguity in the data so I have used GROUP_CONCAT() method of MYSQL.
Here is my query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(a.FirstName," ",a.LastName)) AS Name,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.Email) as Email, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.Contact) as Contact,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.skillName) as Skill, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT d.totalExperience) 
AS Experience from applicant_personal_info a JOIN applicant b ON a.ApplicantID = 
b.ApplicantID JOIN applicant_skills c ON a.ApplicantID = c.ApplicantID 
JOIN applicant_professional_info d ON a.ApplicantID = d.ApplicantID 
WHERE c.skillName = 'HTML'
```

Comment: Well, do not use group_concat()...

Comment: Consider simplifying the problem and, accordingly, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best would be to not concat any of your data. You will then have separate rows that you will be able to use easily. I have also dissociated FirstName and the Name, as it will be easier to use later on - but you can keep this concat if you really need to

```
SELECT a.FirstName AS FirstName,
       a.LastName AS Name,    -- or CONCAT(a.FirstName," ",a.LastName) as Name 
       b.Email AS Email,
       a.Contact AS Contact,
       c.skillName AS Skill,
       d.totalExperience AS Experience
FROM applicant_personal_info a
JOIN applicant b ON a.ApplicantID = b.ApplicantID
JOIN applicant_skills c ON a.ApplicantID = c.ApplicantID
JOIN applicant_professional_info d ON a.ApplicantID = d.ApplicantID
WHERE c.skillName = 'HTML'
```

You will get :

```
"data": [
    {
        "FirsName": "faseeh",
        "Name": "tauheed",
        "Email": "faseeh@gmail.com",
        "Contact": "923158414969",
        "Skill": "HTML",
        "Experience": "36"
    },
    {
        "FirstName": "Muhammad",
        "Name": "Saeed",
        "Email": "saeed@gmail.com",
        "Contact": "923132347067",
        "Skill": "HTML",
        "Experience": "72"
    },
    {
        "FirstName": "Farhan",
        "Name": "Khan",
        "Email": "farhan@gmail.com",
        "Contact": "923471220797",
        "Skill": "HTML",
        "Experience": "48"
    }
]
```

If you only need to get the first row of data, add this line at the end of your query :

```
 LIMIT 1;
```

--

Last but not least, if you definitely need to use these CONCAT for a reason or another, you could split these data with nodes. Your SQL statement is already complicated enough, even if you get it done correctly by over-complexing it, it will be a nightmare to maintain and change in a couple of months if required.

--
Edit :

```
SELECT CONCAT('"',
         a.FirstName , '", "',
         a.LastName , '", "',
         b.Email , '", "',
         a.Contact , '", "',
         c.skillName , '", "',
         d.totalExperience , '"') as user
FROM applicant_personal_info a
JOIN applicant b ON a.ApplicantID = b.ApplicantID
JOIN applicant_skills c ON a.ApplicantID = c.ApplicantID
JOIN applicant_professional_info d ON a.ApplicantID = d.ApplicantID
WHERE c.skillName = 'HTML'
```

should give :

```
"data": [
    {
        "User": "\"faseeh\", \"tauheed\", \"faseeh@gmail.com\", \"923158414969", \"HTML\", \"36\""
    },
    {
... with all the other users in the same format
]
```

The \" is only here to represent the fact that the double quotes will probably be escaped in your json

Comment: If you DEFINITELY need to use all these concat, please explain us why, it will help clarify your question

Comment: Could you be more specific ? Do you have any data ? If yes, why isn't it satisfying ? If no, is it a SQL syntax error ? If it is, maybe you can correct it - without the proper database and data on my machine, I haven't written a syntax-proof answer, but a great way for you to help you to get to the answer a lot quicker.

Comment: if i'll not use group_concat() than there will be ambiguity in data each filed of record is repeating twins

Comment: What do you mean by ambiguity in this situation ?

Comment: means repetition of data

Comment: In the example above, there is no repetition of data at all, apart from the Experience (HTML). Here, you have multiple rows. If you want just ONE row, add the "LIMIT 1" at the end of your query, as advised:

Comment: If you have multiple time the same person in your database, you would better make sure sanitize your data, rather than developing work-around.

Comment: i have a single record of each person in database and the example i gave above is the free from repetition, but my question is that i want the of an individual separately, not in the above format i had shown in my question. And if i set the limit one than no other record is showing accept the first one

Comment: OK, now I understand what you mean. Your original idea was the correct one : using CONCAT. But the GROUP_CONCAT and DISTINCT in your code mislead people on stackoverflow into believing you wanted something else, more complex. If the latest edit satisfy you, I will delete the rest of the answer to only keep the latest edit

Comment: Any success @ahsan-alam ?